# Got the error in Fultter 'Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name' which try to import class models

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I just create class Table in flutter models and now try to assign in json form. I create class Table from quicktype which I got as below

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final table = tableFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Table tableFromJson(String str) => Table.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String tableToJson(Table data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Table {
  Table({
    this.name,
    this.seat,
  });

  String name;
  String seat;

  factory Table.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Table(
        name: json["name"],
        seat: json["seat"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "seat": seat,
      };
}
```

Now I try to assign name and seat but got the error

```
    Table data = Table(name: inputTable.text, seat: inputSeat.text);
    http.Response response = await Connect().post('table/create/', data);
  }
```

My error is

The named parameter 'name' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'name'.

Comment: `Table(this.name,this.seat);` Remove `{}`.

Comment: Still got error in factory name

`factory Table.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`

Comment: is it same error ?

Comment: No, now error change to inside of factory in models/table.dart

Comment: From the first error you posted, it is in which line?

Comment: It's inside my tablepage.dart which I want to http.post to my backend and then I want to send json so I type my json form in quicktype.io and then I apply to use it but I got error.

Comment: Did you try to restart your IDE?

Comment: Already restart. I really don't know what happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your classname and constructor name as they can be reversed classes of material

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I change to tablelist and it work fine.